# Is there a fast way to get the net work from this figure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, work, volume

I am trying to interpret this figure that shows the pressure-volume relationship in the lung of a human being. As I was taught in college, the area under a curve is the work done during a volume interval.

[image: Graph]

As such, I calculated the area under those curves.

To do this,

First: I stated the points that make each line in the figure

Second: I converted from mmHg to Pascals as to get the gauge pressure (which is the pressure represented by the graph)

Third: I calculated the actual pressure of the lung

Fourth: I formed the equation for each line in the figure

Fifth: I integrated in the corresponding intervals as to get the area under each curve.

If there is a need to analyze my whole procedure you can find it here:

https://sites.google.com/view/random123abc/home

Adding the area under the corresponding curves I could get the work done while exhaling and the work done while inhaling.

By the sign conventions of the thermodynamics work done by the system is negative and work done on the system is positive.

As such, I just have to add both works without any change in sign since they already match their nature (The work while inhaling is negative and the work while exhaling is positive)
(Am I right on that?)

However, this process took me along time. Could anyone please tell me if there is a simpler and/or faster way to get the net work done by this human lung.

Comment: Since the curves are straight lines, you can just compute the area using the formulas for areas of rectangles and triangles.  No need to find equations of the lines and integrate.

Comment: This seems perilously close to an [off-topic check-my-work question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) about finding the area of a quadrilateral. Also, have you swapped “inhale” versus “exhale”? For air to enter the lungs, the “gauge pressure” must be negative, but you have “inhale” on the high-pressure curve.

Comment: The net work is the area enclosed by the cycle

Comment: The system you are studying is not closed. When the pressure in the lungs increases we get more air in; when pressure decreases so does the amount of air in the lungs. The formula $$W =-\int P dV$$ assumes that volume $V$ contains a fixed amount of gas, which then expands or contracts against external pressure $P$.

Comment: This can easily be done using areas of trapezoids, which are equal to half the sum of the two parallel sides times the altitude.  On the inhaling, you have two trapazoids of areas (0.3)(9+1)/2=1.5 mm.L and (0.9)(9+11)/2 = 4.5 mm.L.  For exhaling, you have two trapezoids of areas (0.9)(1+2)/2= 1.25 mm.L and (0.4)(2+11)/2=2.6 mm.L.  So the net area is 1.5+4.5-1.25-2.6=2.15 mm.L.   To get the net work in liter-atm, you divide this by 760. This works out to be about 0.28 J.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a simpler method for step 4,5, which uses the fact that every line is a straight line.

Divide the figure into two triangles. I will show it for the triangle going from near the origin to exhaling to inhaling. I will call these points O, E, I respectively. We have that OE is described by the vector $\begin{pmatrix}0.9\\1.0\end{pmatrix}$ and OI is described by $\begin{pmatrix}0.3\\8.0\end{pmatrix}$. Then we can use the fact that the [cross product](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-cross-product.html) between two vectors can be used to calculate the area of the triangle between the two vectors:
$$\text{area between $\vec u$, $\vec v$}=\tfrac 1 2|\vec u \times \vec v|$$
Calculating the cross product:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0.9\\1.0\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}0.3\\8.0\end{pmatrix}=0.9\cdot8.0-1.0\cdot 0.3=6.9$$
Taking half gives $3.45$, but this is in units of mmHg*L so you still would have to do the necessary conversions.

Comment: Using areas of trapezoids, I get 2.15 mmHg*L